# std::numeric_limits<int>::has_infinity + Conditional ternary operator

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was just trying few things on std::numeric_limits. And observed some interesting behaviour.

```
cout << "Min = " << (std::numeric_limits<int>::has_infinity) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
```

outputs `0`

```
cout << "Min = " << (std::numeric_limits<int>::has_infinity ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

outputs `FALSE`

Please notice the position of start and end `()` braces around `std::numeric_limits`

In the first case ternary operator didn't had any meaning. Where as when I shift the brace to the end then only ternary operator (`?:`) is found to be meaningful.

Any inputs on why this behaviour?

Comment: This discussion is orthogonal to `std::numeric_limits`.

Comment: Compiling it gives me `error: ‘template<class _Tp> struct std::numeric_limits’ used without template parameters
  cout << "Min = " << (std::numeric_limits::has_infinity) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";`.

Comment: Note also `std::boolalpha`.

Answer (score 11):

It's the [precedence of the << operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Your first expression is equivalent to:

```
(cout << "Min = " << (std::numeric_limits::has_infinity)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
```